# DataTables warning: table id={id} - Requested unknown parameter '{parameter}' for row {row-index}, column{column-index}`

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable, datatables

I'm using dataTables to make table for my json data. I recieve data from server and that is like:

```
var BillingDate = [
          {"branchcode":"668",
          "saleyear":"99",
          "saleprd":"3",
          "LastX":"36.649717",
          "LastY":"52.488193",
          "flag":"1",
          "flag_Title":null
          },
          {
            "branchcode":"669",
          "saleyear":"99",
          "saleprd":"3",
          "LastX":"36.712585",
          "LastY":"52.935543",
          "flag":"1",
          "flag_Title":null
          },
          {"branchcode":"668",
          "saleyear":"99",
          "saleprd":"3",
          "LastX":"36.649717",
          "LastY":"52.488193",
          "flag":"1",
          "flag_Title":null
          },
          {
            "branchcode":"669",
          "saleyear":"99",
          "saleprd":"3",
          "LastX":"36.712585",
          "LastY":"52.935543",
          "flag":"1",
          "flag_Title":null
          },
          {"branchcode":"668",
          "saleyear":"99",
          "saleprd":"3",
          "LastX":"36.649717",
          "LastY":"52.488193",
          "flag":"1",
          "flag_Title":null
          },
          {
            "branchcode":"669",
          "saleyear":"99",
          "saleprd":"3",
          "LastX":"36.712585",
          "LastY":"52.935543",
          "flag":"1",
          "flag_Title":null
          },
          {"branchcode":"668",
          "saleyear":"99",
          "saleprd":"3",
          "LastX":"36.649717",
          "LastY":"52.488193",
          "flag":"1",
          "flag_Title":null
          },
          {
            "branchcode":"669",
          "saleyear":"99",
          "saleprd":"3",
          "LastX":"36.712585",
          "LastY":"52.935543",
          "flag":"1",
          "flag_Title":null
          }
  
        ];
```

and my table code is like:

```
function CreateTablePagination(ID,data) {
        $(ID).DataTable( {
            data: data,
            columns: [
                { "title": "branchcode" },
                { "title": "year" },
                { "title": "period" },
                { "title": "LastX" },
                { "title": "LastY" },
                { "title": "flag" }
            ]
        } );
    }
```

I've tried debugger and console.log. both showed my data clearly, but there is no data in table because of thr error.

the div container where my code is there is like:

```
<div class="ChartDiv">

    <table id="OMID_DetailTable" class="display" width="100%"></table>
          <div id="chartdiv">
          </div>
</div>
```

but I keep recieving error for :

```
DataTables warning: table id={id} - Requested unknown parameter '{parameter}' for row {row-index}, column{column-index}`
```

does anyone know why? and the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have your HTML table defined without any explicit rows, something like this...

```html
<table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
</table>
```

...then your DataTable options need to be configured like the following:

```js
  var BillingDate = [ {...}, {...}, ..., {...} ];

  $(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
      data: BillingDate,
      columns: [
        { "title": "branchcode",
          "data": "branchcode" },
        { "title": "year",
          "data": "saleyear" },
        { "title": "period",
          "data": "saleprd" },
        { "title": "LastX", 
          "data": "LastX" },
        { "title": "LastY",
          "data": "LastY" },
        { "title": "flag",
          "data": "flag" }
      ]
    } );

  } );
```

Things to note:

1. Because your JSON data array is in a variable called `BillingDate`, this is the name you need to use in your data table:

```
data: BillingDate
```

This tells DataTables where to start, when iterating over the array of row data.

2. Then, you can declare your columns one-by-one - by providing a column heading using `title`, and a datasource using `data`. Each `data` value must exactly match a name used in your JSON objects (one object per row).

Comment: Wow that worked great! :) Thank you a thousand times

Answer (score 0):

Just put your data set in an array rather than object:

```
    var dataSet = [
  ["668","99","3","36.649717","52.488193","1"],
  ["668","99","3","36.649717","52.488193","1"],
  ["668","99","3","36.649717","52.488193","1"],
  ["668","99","3","36.649717","52.488193","1"]
];
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/oda79/pen/MWeRJaM)

Comment: there's no difference... i added another col,too

Comment: make sure your columns' names match your data objects' keys. In the code above they do not

Comment: but I want to name them in specific way... do you mean I have to change the title itself? or what I gave the title?

Comment: I changed and tried them all... still no difference

Comment: Thank you, but I can't. I'm recieving data from server. and that's exactly how it is in my codes

Comment: [https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4#Resolution]  here is where dataTable is talking about the errors... but still I get no answer to how I can display my data

Comment: then here is a working example for your server data, based on andrewjames answer https://codepen.io/oda79/pen/MWeRJaM